# Required attribute in html not working after php captcha conected

Tags: php, html, captcha

im so new with php, but i´m making a webpage with contact form and captcha v.2, but for the captcha to work, it ask me to add a `<input type="button"...`
instead of `type="submit"`, which make the required attribute in the html to not work, and i would like the inputs to be a required field

the captcha is working, and the mail is being sent when checking the not a robot box, but you can send it even if your not filling the fields for email, phone, name...

is anything i can do? or is something im doing wrong?

here is my code:

html:

```
<p>Leave us a message and we'll contact you.</p>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
            <form action="contactoEn.php" method="post" required>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control"  id="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" id="Tel" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="asunto" type="text" class="form-control" id="Title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="comentario" rows="3" class="form-control" id="comentario" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIjB4UAAAAAAe31rx6o6-QewbEFhxbvoyNBZAj"></div>
                <input type="button" value="Send" id="enviar" class="btn-block" onclick="submit()">
          </form>
        </div>
```

php:

```
function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '***********',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<script>alert("Please go back and be sure to check the section I am not a Robot. ");</script>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

    $EmailFrom = "***********";
    $EmailTo = "***********";
    $EmailTo2 = "***********";
    $Nombre = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nombre'])); 
    $Nombre2 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $Nombre3 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['telefono'])); 
    $Nombre4 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['asunto']));
    $Nombre5 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comentario']));
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "<html>";
    $Body .= "<head>";
    $Body .= "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />";
    $Body .= "<title>Untitled Document</title>";
    $Body .= "<style type=\"text/css\">";
    $Body .= "<!--";
    $Body .= "body {";
    $Body .= "  margin-left: 0px;";
    $Body .= "  margin-top: 0px;";
    $Body .= "}";
    $Body .= "-->";
    $Body .= "</style>";

    $Body .= "</head>";

    $Body .= "<body>";
    $Body .= "<table width=\"655\" height=\"24\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
    $Body .= "  <tr>";
    $Body .= "    <td><img src=\"http://***********/img/logo/masARO_LogoTopReferente.png\"  /></td>";
    $Body .= "  </tr>";
    $Body .= "  <tr>";
    $Body .= "    <td class=\"texto_tit_chico\">Hemos recibido un mensaje de: $Nombre<br><br></td>";
    $Body .= "  </tr>";
    $Body .= "  <tr>";
    $Body .= "    <td class=\"texto_fecha_contenido\">Email:$Nombre2<br>Telefono:$Nombre3<br>asunto:$Nombre4<br>Mensaje:$Nombre5<br> </td>";
    $Body .= "  </tr>";

    $Body .= "  <tr>";
    $Body .= "    <td><div align=\"center\" class=\"texto_mas_eventos\"><br>Enviado desde pagina de español<br></div></td>";
    $Body .= "  </tr>";
    $Body .= "  <tr>";
    $Body .= "    <td>&nbsp;</td>";
    $Body .= "  </tr>";
    $Body .= "</table>";
    $Body .= "</body>";
    $Body .= "</html>";
    $Subject = "*********** - Contáctanos";

    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: *********** <$EmailFrom>\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n");
    $success = mail($EmailTo2, $Subject, $Body, "From: *********** <$EmailFrom>\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n");
    echo '<script>alert("Message sent, Thank you");</script>';
}
```

i hope is the correct way to ask this
thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the `submit()` function to check the captcha and then submit the form. You need to perform all the checks for required inputs in that function.

Comment: does that goes in the php? right?, btw thanks so much

Comment: No, it goes in the Javascript `function submit()`.

Comment: Since you call that with `onclick="submit()"`

Comment: this is what i end up with and it work :

Comment: function valida()
        {
            if(document.form1.nombre.value=="")
            {
                alert("No escribio nombre");
                document.form1.nombre.focus();
                return false;
            }else if(document.form1.email.value=="")
            {
                alert("No escribio Correo Electrónico");
                document.form1.email.focus();
                return false;
            }...

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: If you came up with a solution, post it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i end up with and it work :

```
function valida() { 
  if(document.form1.nombre.value=="") { 
    alert("No escribio nombre"); 
    document.form1.nombre.focus(); 
    return false; 
}
  else if(document.form1.email.value=="") { 
   alert("No escribio Correo Electrónico"); 
   document.form1.email.focus(); return false; 
}...
```